# returned size of tensorflow's dataset API is not constant

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, bigdata, tensorflow-datasets

I am using tensorflow's [dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset). And testing my code with simple case. Below shows the simple code I used. The problem is, when the dataset size is small, it seems the returned size from dataset API is not consistent. I'm sure there is a proper way to deal with it. But even though I read all the function in that page and tutorial, I could not find that.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data_source = tf.zeros([24, 200, 64, 64, 1]) #[number_of_video, steps, pixel_w, pixel_h, channel]
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_source)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100)
dataset = dataset.batch(16)
dataset = dataset.repeat()

iterator = tf.contrib.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
next_element = iterator.get_next()
training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(training_init_op)
    next_elem = next_element.eval()
    print(np.shape(next_elem))
    next_elem = next_element.eval()
    print(np.shape(next_elem))
    next_elem = next_element.eval()
    print(np.shape(next_elem))
    next_elem = next_element.eval()
    print(np.shape(next_elem))
    next_elem = next_element.eval()
    print(np.shape(next_elem))
    next_elem = next_element.eval()
    print(np.shape(next_elem))
    next_elem = next_element.eval()
    print(np.shape(next_elem))
```

The dataset is grayscale video. There are totally 24 sequence of video and step size is all 200. Frame size is 64 by 64 and single channel. I set batch size as 16 and buffer size as 100. But the result of the code is,

```
(16, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(8, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(16, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(8, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(16, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(8, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(16, 200, 64, 64, 1)
```

The returned size of video is either 16 or 8. I guess it is because the original data size is small, 24, when it reaches the end of data, the API just returns what is left.

But I don't understand. I also set buffer size as 100. That means the buffer should be filled in advance with small dataset. And from that buffer, the API should select next_element whose batch size if 16.

When I used queue-type API in tensorflow, I didn't have this problem. Whatever the size of original data is, anyway there is an moment when the iterator reaches the end of dataset. I wonder how this problem is solved by other people using this API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to call `repeat()` before `batch()`:

```
data_source = tf.zeros([24, 200, 64, 64, 1]) #[number_of_video, steps, pixel_w, pixel_h, channel]
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_source)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.batch(16)
```

The result I get:

```
(16, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(16, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(16, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(16, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(16, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(16, 200, 64, 64, 1)
(16, 200, 64, 64, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to solve the problem:

```
batched = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(128))
```

Comment: When answering, please provide more explanation.